# Как применить метод ко всем объектам Queryset'а в форме

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, forms

У меня есть Queryset пользователей:

`forms.py`:

```
companion_queryset = User.objects.exclude(id=user.id)
```

И вот мое поле, где нужно выбрать собеседника:

`forms.py`:

```
companion = forms.ModelChoiceField(
            label='Собеседник',
            queryset=companion_queryset,
            widget=forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'style': 'width: 300px;'}),
            # empty_label='',
            required=True,
            )
```

По умолчанию у меня в списке пользователи отображаются как электронные почты, а мне надо как First name и Second name - это 2 поля в модели CustomUser, для отображения Имени и Фамилии у меня есть метод get_full_name(), но я не знаю как его применить к каждому объекту Queryset'а.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться методом `annotate` и создать для каждого объекта поле `full_name` затем через `values_list` получить эти поля.

```py
from django.db.models import Value
from django.db.models.functions import Concat

queryset = User.objects.annotate(
            full_name=Concat('first_name', Value(' '), 'last_name')
            ).values_list('full_name', flat=True)
print(queryset)
```

у меня в базе 3 пользователя, вывод:

```
<QuerySet ['Джеймс Бонд', 'Иван Петров', 'Алиса Петрова']>
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'all'

Comment: откуда `all` взялось

Comment: File "app\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 1491, in _set_queryset
    self._queryset = None if queryset is None else queryset.all()
                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: Джанго сам вызывает метод

Comment: тогда наверное методом не получится, но можно сделать, как в обновленном ответе, и у тебя будет в `queryset-e` лежать объект `Queryset` и ошибок не должно быть.

Comment: Ура, спасибо, заработало